# Laravel 4 - Getting the user id of the user that isnt me

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a SQL query that is quite simple, just a

```
select id, user_one, user_two from users
```

Which returns the following array

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#189 (3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "18" ["user_one"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_two"]=> string(1) "2" } }
```

What i want to do is get the ID of the person that isnt me

So, to get my ID, i simply use

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
```

My ID will be in either user_one or user_two

Can anyone give me a hand?

Cheers,

Comment: Why are you passing your user ID if you don’t want your record in the first place? Just omit it, unless I’m missing something?

Comment: Im not passing my user id ... the sql gets an id of the table and 2 user id's

Comment: Where does it get the IDs from?

Comment: Not sure if I understood this correctly. It doesn't make much sense to me, but then I don't know your situation: `$otherUserId = Auth::user()->id == Auth::user()->user_one ? Auth::user()->user_two : Auth::user()->user_one`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just modify your SQL a little bit.

`"SELECT 
    ID,
    IF(user_one != '".Auth::user()->id."',user_one,user_two) AS not_me 
FROM 
    users`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to query the user by the other id, how about using just `User::where('user_two', '=', 2)`?

You should be able to get the the other user id from the authenticated user by `$second_user = Auth::user()->user_two`.

Hope these helps.